# Variable is not assigned when destroying it´s child though it is assigned?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, reference

I'm very much stuck with this piece of code. I am not gonna post the whole code just the relevant pieces.

The problem is: 
When the player drops a item, so basically drops the child of the mainhand or supporthand (Inventory Slots) then it will give the following error: 
'The Variable 'mainhand' has not been assigned.'

However the variable has been assigned and the script works how it is intended to work. I just want to get rid of the error. Any ideas?

Please help!

```
 public bool handsFull = false;
        public Transform mainHand;
        public Transform supportHand;

        public GameObject player;
        public GameObject[] Items;

        public float throwDistance = 2f;

void Update () {
    //Dropping Items
            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.G)) {

                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) && mainHand.childCount > 0) {
                    GameObject itemToDrop = mainHand.GetChild(0).gameObject;
                    DropItem (itemToDrop);


                }
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1) && supportHand.childCount > 0) {
                    GameObject itemToDrop = supportHand.GetChild(0).gameObject;
                    DropItem (itemToDrop);



                }

            }
}

public void DropItem(GameObject itemToDrop)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.Length; i++) {
            GameObject itemDropped;
            if (Items[i].name == itemToDrop.name) {
                itemDropped = (GameObject)Instantiate (Items [i], itemToDrop.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                itemDropped.tag = "Item";
                itemDropped.name = itemToDrop.name;
                Destroy (itemToDrop);
                itemDropped.transform.SetParent (null);
                itemDropped.transform.Translate (0, 0, throwDistance);
                itemDropped = null; 
                itemToDrop = null;
                return;

                //hand not defined? -

            }


        }
}
```

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/627750/the-variable-has-not-been-assigned-but-it-has.html

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: @SimoErkinheimo Well I read that but the mainhand/supporthand are not prefabs, nor are they ever removed from the scene. Nothing is ever done to those variables. So the link is not helping me sadly. Any ideas?

Comment: @Gusman when I drop it. It does not specify a clear line. Somewhere in the DropItem void. Those lines run at the same time

Comment: In the stack trace from the exception the line must be stated.

Comment: @Gusman I tested it per line now. It is the Destroy (itemToDrop) that throws the exception

Comment: @Gusman Never mind! My bad. Did not see that. It is line 46!

Comment: and what's in that line? maybe better paste the full stack trace, Destroy must be firing some code that uses mainHand variable, do you have something on the dispose of the object which uses that?

Comment: dude you're setting `itemDropped = null;`  WTF ?

Comment: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable mainHand of PlayerEquip has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the mainHand variable of the PlayerEquip script in the inspector.
PlayerEquip.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerEquip.cs:46) @Gusman

Comment: That is not the problem though @JoeBlow

Comment: that's exactly the problem, check the line 46, that's what throws the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple, Unity is not OO.

Don't forget, your script above...

## ...only exists as a component of some GameObject ... attached to a GameObject.

It's very likely that there is SOME GameObject somewhere, that has the script attached. You don't know about it or you forgot about it.

(*) Remember too that Prefabs can easily catch you out in Unity.  Don't forget you can only set inspector drags "within" prefabs in Unity - it's a bit confusing. In a prefab, you can't connect to anything in the "outside world", to the scene.

Comment: Oh god. I feel stupid. Thanks man. It was indeed another object in the scene that I put it on accidently. Did not notice because it was in the anatomy of the character.

Comment: Nothing stupid in the slightest, when I first started using Unity it took me 3 years to figure that out, cheers